# error_code 129 in VK api appWidgets.saveAppImage

Tags: php, api, curl, vk

Good day! I'm trying to load an image using the method appWidgets.saveAppImage. In the beginning I receive URL the server for loading -> getAppImageUploadServer, there all ok!
I receive a hash and an image, send them a POST request and get an error. Here is my code:

```
$token = "Service_access_key";

$tmp_image = file_get_contents('https://www.ejin.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/667108931864_667108931864-150x150.jpg');

file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/tmp.jpg',$tmp_image);
$img_path = dirname(__FILE__).'/tmp.jpg';

$post_data = array("image" => "@".$img_path);

$upload_url = file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/appWidgets.getAppImageUploadServer?v=5.85&image_type=50x50&access_token=".$token);
$url = json_decode($upload_url)->response->upload_url;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch),true);

$safe = file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/appWidgets.saveAppImage?v=5.85&hash=".$result['hash']."&image=".$result['image']."&access_token=".$token);
echo $safe;
```

echo:

```
"error_code":129,"error_msg":"Invalid photo: file not found, from upl_850128?act=app_widget_image"
```

what's my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?

$request_params = array( 
    'image_type' => '510x128',
    'access_token' => 'xxx',
    'v' => '5.92' 
); 

$t = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/appWidgets.getAppImageUploadServer?'. http_build_query($request_params)));

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $t->response->upload_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("image" => new CURLFile(dirname(__FILE__).'\img.jpg')));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, true);
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close($ch);

$request_params = array( 
    'hash' => $result->hash,
    'image' => $result->image,
    'access_token' => 'xxx',
    'v' => '5.92' 
); 

print_r(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/appWidgets.saveAppImage?'. http_build_query($request_params)));

?>
```

Comment: and what does this code do? can you be more descriptive on how this should help and what's wrong with OP solution?

Comment: In PHP 5.6+, the new way to transfer files is to use new CURLFile($localFile), instead of '@'.$localFile.